# Can't read JSON using file_get_contents

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm getting null (blank page) from this:

api.php code:

```
$json_data = array(
    'status' => 'failed',
    'version' => '0.0.5'
);
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($json_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

getapi.php code:

```
$json_file = file_get_contents("http://domain.com/api.php");
$json_data = json_decode($json_file);
print_r($json_data);



    $json_file = file_get_contents("http://domain.com/api.php");
echo $json_file; //{"status":"failed","version":"0.0.5"}
    $json_data = json_decode($json_file);
    print_r($json_data); // blank page
```

Comment: $json_file = file_get_contents("http://domain.com/api.php"); *

Comment: your both page are in the same working directory (in the same folder)? or you are trying server file(getapi.php) to access from your local system?

Comment: @penchY: That's what the "edit" link is for. I've made that change, and generally cleaned up the question for you, including making the title useful.

Comment: For the above to work, `api.php` would have to be running on a web server responding on `http://domain.com`. So...is it? What happens if you open `http://domain.com/api.php` in a browser, what do you see?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, open api.php : {"status":"failed","version":"0.0.5"}

Comment: Is your content being displayed if you open api.php in your browser?

Comment: you have to use `include` because `file_get_contents()` will not work with php outputs content `echo`.

Comment: @Anant: `file_get_contents` can read from URLs just fine, says so right in the docs.

Comment: The above works (I've checked). Whatever the problem is, it's with something not shown in the question. (That is, assuming that you have `<?php` at the beginning and `?>` at the end, which you haven't shown.)

Comment: @penchY: Read the above: **"Whatever the problem is, it's not shown in your question."**

Comment: @T.J.Crowder:     $json_data = json_decode($json_file);
    print_r($json_data); not work .. return blank page not array

Comment: What happens if you print the `$json_file` variable before decoding?

Comment: @penchY: Yes, it does, in the normal case. So there's something unusual in your case. Peter had a good idea what it might be, perhaps that wasn't it, but just repeating "it doesn't work" is not useful.

Comment: @Peter: print $json_file  .. return {"status":"failed","version":"0.0.5"}

Comment: My last suggestion is to check the PHP versions on the two servers. Maybe one of the servers cannot work with `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` since it is supported from > PHP 5.4

Comment: @Peter: my php version 5.6.17

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another answer I would like to submit is the one of trying to debug your json string since you have already told us that the content is pulled in correctly by your `file_get_contents()`

I have the following script from the PHP.net documentation on `json_last_error()`

```
echo 'Decoding: ' . $string;
json_decode($json_file);

switch (json_last_error()) {
    case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
        echo ' - No errors';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
        echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
        echo ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
        echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
        echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
        echo ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
    break;
    default:
        echo ' - Unknown error';
    break;
}

echo PHP_EOL;
```

#### Edit

It looks like you are having trouble with your character set. Try forcing utf-8 as follows.

Change:

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
```

To:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Decoding: ï»¿{"status":"failed","version":"0.0.5"} - Syntax error, malformed JSON

Comment: Simply remove the `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` parameter and see if it works.

Comment: remove JSON_PRETTY_PRINT and not work .. http://i.imgur.com/IoF2tSX.png , http://i.imgur.com/TaJa6QC.png , http://i.imgur.com/ES4owpD.png

Comment: change coding from UTF8 on UTF8 without BOM = all working :) thx :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably with your PHP.ini file and your PHP settings not allowing you to acces remote urls.

The setting you are looking for is `allow_url_fopen`.

You have two ways of getting around it without changing php.ini, one of them is to use `fsockopen()`, and the other is to use cURL.

If you have access to your php.ini file though, I would suggest editing it.

#### Some reading

[Documentation on allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php)

Answer (score 0):

By the first you should be sure that your api.php is available through HTTP.
open URL http://domain.com/api.php in some browser to check, you must see the available response.
If you still see blank page then probably your webserver is not configured properly or api.php file store in not public folder aka. public_html or web.
Run following command:

```
 $ php -i|grep 'allow_url_fopen'
 allow_url_fopen => On => On
```

Also please check your PHP configuration, option [allow-url-fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) should be set to true.
Also please pay attention that constant [JSON_PRETTY_PRINT](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) available since PHP 5.4.0

Next snippet will help you to troubleshoot, place it on the top of your script, but don't forget to remove them after:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', true);
```

Comment: not return errors 
`echo $json_file; //{"status":"failed","version":"0.0.5"}`
`print_r($json_data); // blank page `

Comment: You encoded you JSON with JSON_PRETTY_PRINT but 
   echo $json_file; //{"status":"failed","version":"0.0.5"} <--- not pretty printed?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use function above instead json_decode, it include utf8 fix inside

```
function parseJson($content, $options = true)
{
    $content = fixUtf8String(trim($content));

    $decoded = json_decode(utf8_decode($content), $options);

    if (($jsonLastErr = json_last_error()) != JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        switch ($jsonLastErr) {
            case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
                throw new Exception('JSON Decoding failed: Maximum stack depth exceeded');
            case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
                throw new Exception('JSON Decoding failed: Unexpected control character found');
            case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
                throw new Exception('JSON Decoding failed: Syntax error');
            default:
                throw new Exception('JSON Decoding failed');
        }
    }

    return $decoded;
}

function fixUtf8String($s)
{
    if (empty($s)) {
        return $s;
    }
    $s = preg_match_all(
        "#[\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\x7E]|
        [\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]|
        \xE0[\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]|
        [\xE1-\xEC\xEE\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}|
        \xED[\x80-\x9F][\x80-\xBF]#x", $s, $m
    );

    return implode("", $m[0]);
```

}

Comment: What is your php version?

Comment: my php version 5.6.17

Comment: I have just run your code snippets locally and it working correctly
php getapi.php 
stdClass Object
(
    [status] => failed
    [version] => 0.0.5
)
{
    "status": "failed",
    "version": "0.0.5"
}stdClass Object
(
    [status] => failed
    [version] => 0.0.5
)

The issue probably in somewhere  other place

Comment: Did you call parseJSON($json_file, true, true)? To see error your third parameter should be true

Comment: Did you copied your code from somewhere? Maybe it was copied with bad character try to remove it and rewrite by yourself?